# How to create a personalized command-line parameter name when trying to run java project

Tags: java, command-line

I am searching for on how to create a personalized command-line parameters when running java.

```
( ex. java MyProject -myUserName myuser -myPassword 1234 )
```

so basically the i just want to put a label to the parameter.
Hope this is possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) is a good library for this.